# i want to fetch all record from my database table without recent added record

Tags: php, mysql

i want to fetch all record from MySQL database table using PHP without last added record

I have 4 Columns in the Table, ID(auto) & title and message.

Comment: do you want to exclude today added records only? what you mean by recent added?

Comment: What did you try before asking here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this, if as you say, ID is `auto_increment`

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID != (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM TABLE) ORDER BY ID";
```

This is selecting all the records from your table, ordered by id, where the id is not the biggest one.